# Get list of installed printers

Tags: command-line, printing, cups

Inside of a script I send a certain file to print using the `lpr` command on an user-selected printer.

The list of the printers, from which the user selects the one to use, I get using the `lpstat -a` command and then considering everything before the first space as the name of the printer.

This works but relies heavily on the specific output format of the `lpstat -a` command. I'm afraid that in the future (or now on different distributions) if the output format changes it will break the script.

So, is there a way to get the names of all the installed printers in a way that is safer than the one I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) is (partly) GPL-licensed, so you could just grab [the source of `lpstat`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cups/)<sup>(1)</sup> and create your own little (GPL-licensed) *give-my-list-of-printers*-program that will never change the way it outputs data.

**(1)** It's in `cups-XX/cups/systemv/lpstat.c`, I just don't understand the versions numbers there.

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately the "script" is actually a Java applet, i cannot change the target system or install new stuff on it.
It's related to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743738/different-java-print-implementation-between-os
And i thought that using lpr instead was a good idea

Comment: Hmm, there's [CUPS4J](http://www.cups4j.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=2), which might or might not be an option... it can *"get printers objects from a CUPS server that can be used to print and monitor jobs"*

Answer (score 4):

I also need a list of printers and had the same concern. Following the above suggestion I checked the source of lpstat.c . I was expecting it to be a suid so it could read "/etc/cups/printers.conf" . I now realise  it does not do this.

Instead it sends a HTTP POST request to localhost:631 where cupsd runs. The request is of the form Content-Type: application/ipp and things such as requested-attributes auth-info-required . The reason not to be more specific is that it uses a non-standard encoding (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) ... so I suspect actually parsing the output of lpstat -a is actually cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

It's been six years since the original question, I'm using Cups 2.2.7
And still 'lpstat -a' returns the name of the printer in the first word.
So I think it is safe to assume that it will continue as the right way to get a list of installed printers.

Comment: Confirmed 'lpstat -a' returns printers